# How can I configure an asp.net core web app to use Windows Auth with a fallback to OAuth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication

I'm creating a website where the majority of users are in the org's Active Directory so enabling 'Windows Authentication' for the web project "just works" (the clients are also on the domain). But the website also needs to let in some users who aren't in AD and their client isn't domain-joined. In this case they would have guest accounts in azure active directory and can be authenticated with OAuth.

So is there a way to have my asp.net core website first try Windows Auth and if that fails try OAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the "just works"-part is, that on IIS level you are only allowing the windows authentication ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)):

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    // ...
}
```

First we need a new app registration in the Azure AD (AAD). Then we need to allow anonymous authentication on a new endpoint and redirect the user to authenticate against the AAD. The official documentation is a great start for the [sign-in redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request).

Otherwise when the guest accounts exist in the AAD, your internal users are probably also managed there, why not only use OAuth authentication for all users? For example as described here [ASP.NET Core sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp).

Comment: The aim was that AD users (the majority) would see no changes to their normal workflow. But searching around some more I'm seeing that the only way this is possible is to have 2 websites, each with a different auth method and slightly different binding. So forcing the AD users to have to use OAuth might be the easiest option.

Comment: Correct, that would certainly be the best option for your case. You may keep in mind, that Windows is legacy authentication (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-block-legacy-authentication).

Comment: Good to know. Then with all this in mind, I think it's reasonable to mark this as the answer.